# Spring Security hasAnyRole not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I´m developing an application with spring security authentication and MongoDB. The authentication method is working fine but only with `ROLE_ADMIN`. All methods that I need authentication for are annotated with:

`@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')")`

When I try to authenticate with a user that has `ROLE_USER` I always get access declined error.

My spring security config is:

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />  
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" 
  access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
<security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/admin/main" 
   authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />

        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" 
               max-sessions="1"/>
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>
```

If I use:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

I get access denied for both `ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_USER`.

If I use:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')" />
```

I can log in with a `ROLE_ADMIN` user but I can´t with `ROLE_USER`.

and in my `LoginService` I have:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        User user = getUserDetail(email);

        userdetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getEmail(), user.getPwd(), enabled,
                accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked,
                getAuthorities(user.getIsAdmin()));

        return userdetails;
    }

    public List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        if (role.intValue() == 0) {
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        } else if (role.intValue() == 1) {
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        }
        System.out.println(authList);
        return authList;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If a user can only have one rol (`ROLE_USER` or `ROLE_ADMIN`), your first example must be `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')` (note the `or`).

Comment: Still

`Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8f0d3531: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@2684c716: Username: sub.coutinho@xxx.xyz; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 1dccqdwf2iq51; **Not granted any authorities**`

Comment: Samething. The autehntication process works but no authorities is given. The stack trace is above.

Comment: What is the problem, the `access` or the `getAuthorities` method?, what print the `System.out.println`, add more prints in the `if role.intValue() == XX` and add the output. It's seems that your method `getAuthorities` dont work, you are sure it is called? Please add the `getuserDetail(email)` method.

Comment: The problem is getAuthorities. The getAuthorities method is being called but i dont know if `role.intValue() == 0` is giving me the error for a normal user (ROLE_USER). Running debug, everything is called but when a user has ROLE_USER not athorities is given to that user.

Comment: Please, add a `System.out.println(role.intValue())` and twho `System.out.println(role.intValue() == X)` and see the result.

Comment: 0 and false. 

So i checked on mongodb and saw that for some rease a normal user field value was saving with different value. No the problem is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have this kind of problem, please try first adding many `System.out.println` (or debug log) to see if your method is working,  also change:

```
hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and hasRole('ROLE_USER')
```

for

```
hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')
```

And check if the `role.intValue() == 0` prints `true` with a `sysout`.

Comment: Do not use 'ROLE_' prefix with `hasRole` and `hasAnyRole`.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-common-built-in

Comment: @sura2k With that we can change to `hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'USER')`!

Answer (score 4):

This

```
access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and hasRole('ROLE_USER')
```

means that both roles must be set the same time and sample code shows that it never happenes, because only one of two roles can be set.

It is different statement from `hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')`  which should be true if at least one of these roles is set. Statment `hasAnyRole` is like `or` not `and` condition.

Comment: Yeah, i changed that but for ROLE_USER is not working.